# Get database information from a Flask app input before submitting

Tags: python, html, flask

So I have a Flask app which ask the user to input some information about customers. On the back-side, I have a database table which have columns *id* and *name* .

I want to do a check, where if the user enters an id in an HTML input box, I will print out the name corresponding to that ID. But I want to do this before the user submits the form.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    data = ""
    if #user input to input box#:
        data = get_data_from_db("name")
    return render_template('index.html', data = data)
```

and a simple html representation would be something like this,

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter customer id"/>
<p> {{ data }} </p>
```

So whenever the user inputs something, I want the information from the database to appear before the post request. Is this possible?

Note: I know about AJAX, but I haven't used it before and I don't know about it's compatibility with Flask.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply remove the attributes once the form is submitted (in jQuery):

```
$("form").submit(function() {
       $(this).children('#in-between').remove();
           });
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the users question with how to go about checking the input, submitting the ajax (which is compatible with Flask) and returning a response. I believe that @gerry is looking for a input validation method.